# Simple VPN software

Tags: vpn, ubuntu

I'm currently in need of a simple VPN software.

It must:

- have Ubuntu packages in apt-get, or at the very least a ppa
- be easy to configure and use (unlike openvpn)
- be secure
- be open source

So far, all I can find for an open source vpn software in Ubuntu's package manager is OpenVpn, however OpenVpn lacks any good tutorials that show how to simply set it up -- without messing with creating a CA or new network interfaces. I am looking for a VPN software with a similar or lower difficulty then setting up SSH with keys.

Comment: john - so far all your posts are asking for product recommendations. That is not what this site is for. Please read our [ask] and [about] pages.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to find one: the nature of VPNs means that you have to configure the kinds of things you're trying to avoid. OpenVPN is as easy as it gets.

Separately, you shouldn't need to work too hard on interface configuration with OpenVPN on Ubuntu; most of the hard work is done for you. But there might also be a decent front end or configuration app that can do it.